# How can I get a copy of a file/document which appears in the Firefox network console?

Tags: firefox, linux-mint, http

I'm looking at the Firefox Developer Console's Network tab, and am seeing that a page I'm on gets some file from a server. I can copy its URL, but wget'ing it doesn't work. Can I somehow get the copy of the file/document which Firefox itself downloaded, and save it to a file?

PS - This shouldn't matter, but: I'm using FF 58 on GNU/Linux Mint 18.3

Comment: From the cache?

Comment: @DavidPostill: Sounds promising, but can you be more specific? I mean, sequence-of-instructions specific?

Comment: `about:cache?storage=disk&context=`

Comment: @DavidPostill: Doing that, I get the "cache entry information" which includes something like binary-file-editor view of the contents. But can I get the actual octets as a file? i.e. without passing that through a script?

Comment: [MZCacheView - View the cache files of Firefox/Mozilla browsers](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/mozilla_cache_viewer.html)

Comment: @DavidPostill: That's a Windows binary and I'm on Linux...

Comment: Sorry, can't help then.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Well, thanks for your help thus far... I'm almost there :-)